# Curl not working when running on window cmd having curl installed, However same command works on git bash

Tags: web-services, curl, post, odata

```
curl -v -X POST "ipaddress" -H 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' -k --data-binary '@Test.png' -H 'Authorization: token'
```

When running above command on git-bash it runs successfully

But when run on window command line having curl installed, same command gets failed and shows the below error:

```
upload completely sent off: 14 out of 14 b
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
```

Comment: Could be the windows version of CURL doesn't support the exact arguments you're supplying, whereas git-bash's version does.

Answer (score 5):

Replace your single quote with double quote. Windows cmd doesn't work with single. For example:

```
curl -v -X POST "ipaddress" -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" -k --data-binary "@Test.png" -H "Authorization: token"
```